How Camunda8 form-js handles dynamic lists
I wanted to create my own version of the default dynamic list, but with a maximum of 5 elements.
But i'm not sure how adding new elements to a dynamic list is handled.
The default dynamic list can add elements to the list by dragging the element over the top.
here you can see the default dynamic list being used.
default dynamic list
I have tried to recreate the dynamic list. But I'm not sure how they handle adding new elements to the list. This is my attempt at dynamic list.
My dynamic list
what i've tried)
I started by building an element that extends the default dynamic list and was basically able to copy the HTML I could see in the dev tools of the browser to get the html of my list list to look like the default list.
import Max5DynamicIcon from "./Max5icon.svg";
import classNames from 'classnames';
export const Max5DynamicType = "Max5Dynamic";



import {
    Errors,
    FormContext,
    Description,
    DynamicList,
    Label
  } from '@bpmn-io/form-js';
  
  import {
    html,
    useContext
  } from 'diagram-js/lib/ui';
  
  export function Max5DynamicRenderer(props) {
  
    const {
      disabled,
      errors = [],
      field,
      readonly,
      value
    } = props;
  
    const {
      description,
      id,
      label
    } = field;
  
    const { formId } = useContext(FormContext);
  
    const errorMessageId = errors.length === 0 ? undefined : `${prefixId(id, formId)}-error-message`;
  
    const onChange = ({ target }) => {
      props.onChange({
        field,
        value: Number(target.value)
      });
    };
  
    return html`
    <div class=${ formFieldClasses(Max5DynamicType) }>
        
        <div role="group" class="fjs-form-field fjs-form-field-dynamiclist fjs-form-field-grouplike fjs-outlined" 
        aria-labelledby=${ prefixId(id, formId) }>

        <${Label}
        id=${ prefixId(id, formId) }
        label=${ label } />

          <div class="fjs-vertical-layout fjs-children cds--grid cds--grid--condensed">  
            <div class="fjs-empty-component">
              <span class="fjs-empty-component-text">
              Drag and drop components here.
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="fjs-repeat-render-footer">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="none">
              <path fill="currentColor" d="M3 3h10.086l-1.793-1.793L12 .5l3 3-3 3-.707-.707L13.086 4H3v3.5H2V4a1 1 0 0 1 1-1M4.707 10.207 2.914 12H13V8.5h1V12a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H2.914l1.793 1.793L4 15.5l-3-3 3-3z">
              </path>
            </svg>
            <span>Repeatable</span>
          </div>
        </div>

        

    </div>
      `;
  }


  Max5DynamicRenderer.config = {
    ...DynamicList.config,
    type: Max5DynamicType,
    label: 'Max5Dynamic',
    iconUrl: `data:image/svg+xml,${ encodeURIComponent(Max5DynamicIcon) }`,
    propertiesPanelEntries: [
      'key',
      'label',
      'description',
      'min',
      'max',
      'disabled',
      'readonly'
    ]
  };
  


  function formFieldClasses(type, { errors = [], disabled = false, readonly = false } = {}) {
    if (!type) {
      throw new Error('type required');
    }
  
    return classNames('fjs-form-field', `fjs-form-field-${type}`, {
      'fjs-has-errors': errors.length > 0,
      'fjs-disabled': disabled,
      'fjs-readonly': readonly
    });
  }
  
  function prefixId(id, formId) {
    if (formId) {
      return `fjs-form-${ formId }-${ id }`;
    }
  
    return `fjs-form-${ id }`;
  }

However I'm completely unable to figure out what to put in CustomPropertiesProvider.js to add the functionality to my list.
I have even downloaded text crawler, to look through every reference to "dynamic list" in every file in the project but still am no wiser.
Text crawler
Question)
How are elements added to a dynamic list? what functions are used or what may i be missing?
I imagine I might need to add stuff to my CustomPropertiesProvider.js but i'm just not sure what?
extra info
I'm using camunda forms. I started by downloading this https://github.com/bpmn-io/form-js-examples/tree/master/custom-components
Here is my current project in case anyone is capable of helping.
https://github.com/jflearnfdtd/Trying_to_recreate_dynamic_list
go to "Trying_to_recreate_dynamic_list\custom-components" and enter "npm run dev" to start
my "Trying_to_recreate_dynamic_list\custom-components\app\extension\render\max5dynamiclist.js" file is where i created my own custom dynamic list.
